# d3.js in visualize china map in geojson format about the projection setting

Tags: d3.js

I want use d3.js to display china map,but when i successfully invert mydata to geojson,the data could not visualize correctly.I think the reason may be the projection. 
  could you help me to overcome it,think you!

```
<script>
var width = 960,
height = 500;
var proj = d3.geo.mercator();
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);
proj.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
proj.scale(5000);
proj.center([105, 35]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

d3.json("mydata.json", function (json) {
    svg.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path);
});
```

mydata.json:
http://mysnspace.sinaapp.com/mydata.json

Answer (score 0):

I used projection equirectangular instead of mercator and generated mine correctly.

B.R.
Ian